# group column base on data inside the column

Tags: python, pandas

I d like to know if is possible group a pandas column base on data inside of that column, I have been doing that in a different way but it s no fine. The assignment require doing with pandas.

Thank so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is an example where `.groupby()` is used to calculate total i.e. `.sum()` quantity of fruits. Here, the `grouped` columns is `fruits` and the `sum` is over `quantity` column. Note that that `.sum()` can be replaced by any other statistic such as `.mean()`, `.count()` etc. Additional information can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html).

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'fruits':['apple','apple','apple','orange','orange'],
    'quantity': [1,2,3,4,5]
})

# Groupby to count total quantity of 'apples' and 'oranges'
dfnew = df.groupby(['fruits'])['quantity'].sum().reset_index()

# Rename columns
dfnew.columns = ['fruits', 'sum_quantity']
```

Output

```
dfnew

   fruits  sum_quantity
0   apple             6
1  orange             9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
variable = data_frame.groupby('column_name')
```

Yes you can easily grouby data using a groupby command on a data frame and passing the column name in as an argument